# How to get the current test filename from RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2

I'm trying to speed up a large RSpec project's tests. In addition to using RSpec's `--profile` option I wanted to get the longest running test files [1] printed out.

In my `spec_helper.rb` I dump the classes being tested and total time to a file, however as we have `spec/model` and `spec/request` directories I'd really like to be able to print the current test's *filename* and not just the class name (`described_class`), so that the user can disambiguate between `model/foo_spec.rb` and `request/foo_spec.rb` when optimizing.

**In a `before` block in the `spec/spec_helper.rb`, how can I get the current test file's filename?**

My (heavily trimmed) `spec_helper` looks like this:

```
config.before :all do
  @start_time = Time.now
end

config.after :all do |test|
  timings.push({ :name => test.described_class,
                 :file => 'I do not know how to get this',
                 :duration_in_seconds => (Time.now - @start_time) })
end

config.after :suite do
  timing_logfile_name = 'log/rspec_file_times.log'
  timing_logfile = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../#{timing_logfile_name}"
  file = File.open(timing_logfile, 'w')
  timings.sort_by{ |timing| timing[:duration_in_seconds].to_f }.reverse!.each do |timing|
    file.write( sprintf("%-25.25s    % 9.3f seconds\n",
                        timing[:name], timing[:duration_in_seconds]) )
  end
  file.close
  tell_if_verbose("Overall test times are logged in '#{timing_logfile_name}'")
end
```

This doesn't seem to be available in the curretn RSpec meta-data, but I'm hoping someone more familiar with the internals can think of a way to expose it. Thanks,
Dave

[1] Often a file with, say, 100 examples in it yields more speed up than a single example from --profile - when that large file's `before :each` / `before :all` blocks are targetted, obviously even a ms saved is multiplied up by the number of tests in the file. Using this technique in addition to `--profile` helped me a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as you're just using this for profiling your tests to identify which files need to be improved, you should be able to toss this into your `spec_helper.rb` file (and remove it afterwards). I fully understand that this is not pretty/clean/elegant/acceptible in production environments and I disavow that I ever wrote it :)

```
config.before(:each) do |example|
  path = example.metadata[:example_group][:file_path]
  curr_path = config.instance_variable_get(:@curr_file_path)
  if (curr_path.nil? || path != curr_path)
    config.instance_variable_set(:@curr_file_path, path)
    puts path
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks; this doesn't directly sort out my current issue as I only seem to have the example metadata in a before :each, and not in the :all. However, I can rewrite until I get close enough to what I want.

Comment: yeah, before :all doesn't get metadata, but what this is essentially doing is whatching each test/example and printing out whenever the source file changes. If you want to dig a little deeper, place a "pp config" call in config.before(:all) then exec one test to dump everything that is in the config object. You might find something useful in there that I missed.

Comment: In order to get access to `example`, I had to change `config.before(:each) do` to `config.before(:each) do |example|` (i.e. I needed to add `|example|`). I assume that this is due to some change in RSpec since this answer was originally written. (I'm currently using RSpec version 3.7.0.)