# How to find the currently running/loaded spec file name inside spec helper

Tags: ruby, rspec, parallel-testing

I have multiple specs, wish to create separate log files per spec with the spec file name. I need to know which spec file is currently loaded in `spec_helper.rb`.

I have to create logger object in spec helper

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) do |example_group|
    loaded_files = config.instance_variable_get("@files_to_run")
    # after getting the current spec file name
    # will create log file here
  end
end
```

`loaded_files` have an array of all the spec files that I chose for execution. I need to know which is currently loaded?

I do not want to put a before(:each) block, it will increase the run time and i just need the filename, not a good solution to use before(:each) block.

Comment: the solution uses a before(:each) i want to find the file name in before(:all)

Answer (score -1):

I hope the following code can help.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) do |example_group|
    path = example.metadata[:example_group][:file_path]
    curr_path = config.instance_variable_get(:@curr_file_path)
    if (curr_path.nil? || path != curr_path)
      config.instance_variable_set(:@curr_file_path, path)
      puts path
    end
  end
end
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891028/how-to-get-the-current-test-filename-from-rspec)

Comment: this doesnt work. I am using before(:all).