# How to get test script file name inside before(:context) in rspec?

Tags: rspec

I have a shared_context in a separate file which is included in the rspec test files.
How can I retrieve current rspec test file name inside context.

# a.rb

```
describe 'Test Description' do
  include_context 'My context'

  it 'Should get to confirmation page' do
    # Test steps
  end
end
```

# b.rb

```
shared_context "My context" do |page_class|
  before(:context) do |example|
    # Want to access test file_name here(i.e. 'a.rb')
  end

  after(:context)
    # Quit browser
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me.
Thanks

I have tried with the answer suggested in the following link,
[How to get the current test filename from RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891028/how-to-get-the-current-test-filename-from-rspec)

But it doesn't work and getting following error:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current test filename from RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891028/how-to-get-the-current-test-filename-from-rspec)

Comment: No, It doesn't solve my problem. I have tried with the answer suggested in the given link.

Furthermore I don't have any spec_helper file. I have added the snapshot of error in the question.

Comment: Can you explain the reason you're trying to do that? The error, about metadata not being available seems to be there by design. Your "shared example" should not change it's behavior based on a spec that is calling it.